# How to send a message in a synchronous function by a bot in python aiogram?

Tags: python, python-requests, telegram-bot

I have a synchronous function and in it I need to implement sending messages using a bot in python aiogram. I found that you can send a message not using bot.send_message (...), but requests.get (...). But this way you cannot specify parse_mode and attach an inline button. Are there any other ways to implement this? For some reason, this option does not work.:

```
requests.get(f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{BOT_TOKEN}/sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&text={parse_message}&reply_markup={open_tp}&parse_mode=HTML")
```

Comment: What is in `parse_message` variable?

Comment: @MyZik string. When i use these variables in await bot.send_message () the code works

Comment: show us the string, it is impossible to help without code

Comment: @MyZik Something like that `<strong>AK-47 | Vulcan (Battle-Scarred)</strong>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to wrap sending the message in this structure:

```
dp.loop.run_until_complete(bot.send_message(STEAMTRADEBOT_UNLIMITED_ID, parse_message, reply_markup = open_tp))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<b>AK-47 | Vulcan (Battle-Scarred)</b>` and not `<strong>` tag. The HTML and Makrdown syntax for Telegram Bot API you can find here:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options

Comment: this does not work. Moreover, I have a button in my message, it is not added either

Comment: pls post full code, why you say aiogram and do it with python requests?

Comment: There is a lot of code, but I can explain it without it. I get such a structure that in an asynchronous function there is a call to a regular function, in which, in turn, a call to another asynchronous function. Because of this structure, I get an error, which can be solved by changing the sending of messages from bot.send_message to requests.get requests. Messages are sent, but all parameters like parse_mode and reply_markup are not taken into account and I receive a message with html tags and without a button